# jQuery closest() isn't working with declared variable

Tags: jquery, css, selector

I am trying to put selectors in variables to be able to reuse them, and for cleaner code. I have this originally:

```
...code...
this.closest('.selectorA').find('.selectorB').find('input').val('Cool');
this.closest('.selectorA').find('.selectorC').find('input').val('Cool2');
this.closest('.selectorA').find('.selectorD').find('input').val('Cool3');
...code...
```

Now I assigned `.selectorA` to `$foo` variable:

```
var $foo = $('.selectorA');

...code...
this.closest($foo).find('.selectorB').find('input').val('Cool');
this.closest($foo).find('.selectorC').find('input').val('Cool2');
this.closest($foo).find('.selectorD').find('input').val('Cool3');
...code...
```

And it doesn't work. I know if I do it like this it will:

```
var $foo = '.selectorA';
```

Question is, is there a way to make it work with this?

```
var $foo = $('.selectorA');
```

`this` refers to the current row of a table, I have a select onchange event that changes the input values of the current row once triggered.

**Update**:

Please see sample: http://jsfiddle.net/superigno/wpLur9y5/

Comment: HTML is needed, how else can we assess if closest() is indeed ...closest to what?

Comment: what is `this`?

Comment: Why don’t you just try $foo = this.closest(‘.selectorA’) and then use it this way: $foo.find(...) ?

Comment: @mis this refers to the current row of a table, I have a select onchange event that changes the input values.

Comment: @yeshashah if I do that, I won't be able to reuse it on other parts of the page

Comment: No, do not try anything but posting your HTML, your understanding of `closest()` is probably wrong. We wouldn't know unless there was HTML to reference. When you give directions to somewhere do you give street names or do you give street names and directions: left, right, north, south, etc.

Comment: Instead if using `this.closest()`, try writing `$(this).closest()`.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
var $foo = this.closest('.selectorA');
```

Then you can

```
$foo.find(….).find(…).val(…);
```

Comment: Thing is I won't be able to use $foo on other parts of the page, as 'this' refers the current row of the table

Comment: @yeshashah something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/superigno/wpLur9y5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yeshas93/wpLur9y5/29/ : I updated your fiddle and its working for me. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

here closest() Method Return the first ancestor of `.selectorA` as well find() Return all `input` elements that are descendants of `.selectorA` for that you must assign your variable with any of that selector before using that methods. then and then it will return selector.
here is a links [closest()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp)   [find()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_find.asp)